# EasyPHP - localhost alias

Tags: php, alias, easyphp

I'm using the latest version of EasyPHP on Windows 10 and I would like to achieve one thing which I cannot find an answer to.

I achieve my projects for example like `localhost/myproject`. Everything is working but it's kind of annoying because my browser's (Google Chrome) autocomplete is kind of useless when all my projects start with `localhost`

I would like to achieve (probably through Apache config) the thing that when I type for example `myproject.dev` in my browser it shows me project `localhost/myproject`. Redirect would be enough but if it worked on the domain the whole time like it does on regular server that would be perfect. So basically I need something like `ngrok` but with custom domains and it does not need to be public.

It does not need to be automatic, I'm OK with setting each domain manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easily achieved.

First add a new line inside `hosts` file, located at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`:

```
127.0.0.1       myproject.dev
```

Then locate `httpd-vhosts.conf` or `httpd.conf` and near the end add:

```
<VirtualHost myproject.dev>
    DocumentRoot "path/to/folder/myproject"
    ServerName myproject.dev
    ServerAlias myproject.dev
    <Directory "path/to/folder/myproject">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: so you're saying that EasyPHP ships with its own httpd-vhosts.conf file?  for some reason I cant find it....

Comment: @klewis Yes, it should be inside the `/conf`directory in the apache installation of easyphp, for me its in `EasyPHP-Devserver-17/eds-binaries/httpserver/apache2425vc11x86x190513150855/conf`

Answer (score 1):

you want to create a Vhost

`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/configure-virtual-host-on-windows-10-for-wordpress/